# for ring $A$ and prime numbers $p,q$, $p=q=0\in A$, then $p=q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $A$ be commutative ring with identity $1_A$, and $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$ be prime numbers.

If $p\cdot 1_A=q\cdot 1_A=0\in A$, then $p=q\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

I can't prove it and can't make a counter example, so please tell me solutions or hints.

Comment: I'm very confused, they're distinct prime numbers but both are the additive identity?

Comment: A ring has only one additive identity so $p=q$, yes, but this is completely unrelated to them being prime.

Comment: I note $p\in A$ in a sense of $1_A+\cdots +1_A$ ($p$ times).

Comment: @SwanKlein
Sorry I can't understand what you say. Why can we say $p=q$?

Comment: @Ryu. Because a ring has only one additive identity. If $p$ and $q$ are the additive identity, then there will two additive identity which is not possible. So they must be the same, $p=q$. Notice in my reasoning, nowhere I mentioned their primality. So,$ p=q$  is not related to them being primes.

Comment: "So they must be the same, $p=q$" means $p=q\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) of the ring $A$, which can be defined as the [exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_group) of the additive group of the ring. Now, the additive order of $1$ divides $p$ and $q$, and hence divides the gcd of $p$ and $q$, which is $1$ if $p \not= q$. It follows that $1 = 0$ in this case, thus $A$ is the [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring). Otherwise $p = q$.

Comment: Note that OP didn't say $p$ and $q$ were distinct prime numbers. I believe what they're trying to prove is that if both $p$ and $q$ are both additive identities of the ring, then $p$ and $q$ both equal the same prime number.

Comment: @arbashn Thanks, I have modified my answer to take your remark into account.